# Windows 8 App Local Storage

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, local-storage

I am trying to develop Windows 8 apps using C# and I need to store two list's (string and DateTime) in local settings

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
```

I used LocalSettings for that according to this page:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

But I have problems while I am storing Lists and getting back them from saved settings.

Can you help by sending couple of lines to store and retrieve string List and DateTime list type objects (or some other method to store this kind of data).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one libarary called [Windows 8 Isolated storage](https://isolatedstoragew8.codeplex.com/), it uses XML serialization. You can store `object` as well as `List<T>`. The usage is also so much easy. Just add DLL in your project ans you have methods for storing the data.

```
public class Account
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname{ get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Save in Isolated Storage:

```
Account obj = new Account{ Name = "Mario ", Surname = "Rossi", Age = 36 };
var storage = new Setting<Account>();          
storage.SaveAsync("data", obj);
```

Load from Isolated Storage:

```
public async void LoadData()
{    
    var storage = new Setting<Account>();
    Account obj = await storage.LoadAsync("data");    
}
```

Also If you want to store List :
Save a List in Isolated Storage:

```
List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
accountList.Add(new Account(){ Name = "Mario", Surname = "Rossi", Age = 36 });
accountList.Add(new Account(){ Name = "Marco", Surname = "Casagrande", Age = 24});
accountList.Add(new Account(){ Name = "Andrea", Surname = "Bianchi", Age = 43 });

var storage = new Setting<List<Account>>(); 
storage.SaveAsync("data", accountList );
```

Load a List from Isolated Storage:

```
public async void LoadData()
{    
    var storage = new Setting<List<Account>>();    
    List<Account> accountList = await storage.LoadAsync("data");    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this sample, it demonstrates how to save a collection to application storage: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinStoreAppSaveCollection-bed5d6e6

Answer (score 0):

try this to store:

```
localSettings.Values["names"] = names 
localSettings.Values["dates"] = dates
```

and this to read:

```
dates = (List<DateTime>) localSettings.Values["dates"];
```

edit: it looks like I was wrong, and that you can only store basic types this way. So you may have to serialize everything into, say, a byte[] by using a MemoryStream and saving just its buffer.

Comment: Code seems right but I tried it. App starts correctly but at the runtime I receive this error:

An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Error trying to serialize the value to be written to the application data store

Additional information: Data of this type is not supported.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It seems that the problem is when trying to persist DateTime, as in c# it is not a runtime type (DateTimeOffset is)...Seems that the way is to convert DateTime from and to DateTimeOffset...there must be a more elegant solution. in WP8 IsolatedStorage works fine

Comment: var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current;
var localSettings = applicationData.LocalSettings;