# Copy and Save an image selected by the user in windows store apps using c#

Tags: c#, image, save, windows-store-apps

I need to copy the image that user open and selects and save it and show the saved image to the user whenever an app reloads. help me show to save an image in Windows store app (not a web application).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ApplicationDataContainer`. Save the opened file to application settings, and on loading application get it and show. Example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070308/windows-8-app-local-storage)

Answer (score 1):

How does the user open and select the image? Using `FileOpenPicker`? In this case just copy the `StorageFile` returned by it to the local storage and always retrieve it from there:

```
var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

var copiedFile = await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
```

EDIT:

To display the image use the `Image` control. You can set the source to copied file directly in XAML using the [`ms-appdata` scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh965322%28v=win.10%29.aspx):

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="ms-appdata:///local/CopiedFile.jpg" />
```

Or you can set its source from code:

```
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/CopiedFile.jpg"));
```

There are other ways of course, such as binding the `Source` property from view model), depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: the file is getting stored but it is not being displayed. How to display the stored file

Comment: @lakshmivisalij I've added a couple of samples how to show the image to my answer.

Comment: yeah but that is not working for me and here is my code below

Comment: public async void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser("Opening image file...", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
                StorageFile file = await Helpers.GetFileFromOpenPickerAsync();
                var copiedFile = await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
                Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///LocalFolder/file.jpg"));

Comment: m_fileToken = m_futureAccess.Add(file);
                m_imageProperties = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
                m_imageProperties = await copiedFile.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();

                string[] requests =
                {
                    "System.Photo.ExposureTime",        // In seconds
                    "System.Photo.FNumber"              // F-stop values defined by EXIF spec
                };

Comment: IDictionary<string, object> retrievedProps = await m_imageProperties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(requests); awaitDisplayImageUIAsync(file,GetImagePropertiesForDisplay(retrievedProps));// var copiedFile = await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
IDictionary<string, object> retrievedPropss = await m_imageProperties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(requests);
await DisplayImageUIAsync(copiedFile, GetImagePropertiesForDisplay(retrievedPropss));rootPage.NotifyUser("Loaded file from picker: " + file.Name,NotifyType.StatusMessage);CloseButton.IsEnabled = true;ApplyButton.IsEnabled = true;}

Comment: thats not showing the image after the page is being suspended or renavigated

Comment: public async Task DisplayImageUIAsync(StorageFile file, IDictionary<string, string> propertyText)
        {
            BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
            src.SetSource(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
            Image1.Source = src;
            MyImage.Source = src;
           // MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///Values/copiedFile.jpg"));
            AutomationProperties.SetName(Image1, file.Name);
            AutomationProperties.SetName(MyImage, file.Name);
            TitleTextbox.Text = propertyText["Title"];
        }

Comment: it displays image only when the app is running n when we r in thr same page

Comment: but i want to display the selected image using the image even after the app is suspended or reloaded or navigated

Comment: @lakshmivisalij How about editing your question and posting your code properly there to make it easier for me to read?